# odbc driver does not support the requested properties VB6

Tags: mysql, sql, vb6, ado

I'm Giovanni, and I try to execute SQL Command on VB6.

But there was contains an error like this :
"odbc driver does not support the requested properties"

Here is my SQL code on my program :

```
  dung = "SELECT pkg_guru.id_soal, soal_pkg.isi_soal, pkg_guru.jawaban, pkg_guru.kompetensi" & _
    "FROM pkg_guru INNER JOIN soal_pkg ON pkg_guru.id_soal = soal_pkg.id_soal " & _
    "WHERE pkg_guru.id_pkg = '" & F02_MulaiPKG.CBox.Text & "' AND pkg_guru.id_soal = '" & Val(txtno.Caption) & "' + 1 ORDER BY pkg_guru.id_soal ASC"

    rsSoal.Open dung, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

When I run on SQLYog Ultimate, the code work normally and shows it results

Can you tell me the solution?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string:

```
"...pkg_guru.kompetensi" & _
"FROM pkg_guru INNER JOIN soal_pkg ON pk
```

results in `kompetensiFROM` which is invalid; add a space.

The statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks (passing a string variable containing `'`)  Use a [parametrized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675101(v=vs.85).aspx) to avoid this.

The firehose `adopenstatic, adlockreadonly` options are better for a simple read-only recordset if thats what your after.